# How to remove space followed by a comma in comma separated array in Angular Split method?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, split

I have a comma separated string value. And using split() method, I'm converting it to a array.
But in some cases if user put space after a comma, it will create an extra space between word.

Please refer to the code and the image .

**.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">

<input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="title">
<button (click)="addTitle(myForm.value)">Save</button>

</form>
```

**.ts**

```
public title = " ";

public myForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    title: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
  });

  addTitle(value: any){
    this.title = value.title;
    const array = this.title.split(',');
    console.log('array',array);
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like the following:

```
addTitle(value: any){
    this.title = value.title;

    // here the trim() function will remove he white space from each element
    const array = this.title.split(',').map(s => s.trim());
    console.log('array',array);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. But In this case, if user types something like 'General Manager' (Two words) . It will also separated in to 2 elements isn't it? So it's not correct right? :)

Comment: true, I edited my answer to fix that. It should be okay now.